# How to improve Adobe Brackets auto indentation

Tags: html, indentation, autoindent, brackets

I'm looking for a way to auto-indent my [html](/questions/tagged/html) code using Adobe Brackets.

Currently when I selected the whole code (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and use the inbuilt indent option using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>,

The entire text moves a tab forward. What I'm looking for is to properly auto indent the code, for example the way in which [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)'s *Tidy Up* option works.

---

or In other words, I want the following:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<span>
</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

To become:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Rather than simply moving a tab distance forward like:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
    <span>
    </span>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I've tried searching and read the [preferences](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/How-to-Use-Brackets#preferences) but couldn't figure out a way to do this. Any ideas..?

Comment: Looks like they have extensions. I found Beautify @ https://brackets-registry.aboutweb.com/

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Wow that did it beautifully...! Care to post that as an answer..?!

Comment: Sure thing! done :)

Comment: I am comparing Atom and Brackets now... seems like Atom can re-indent quite well, so far, for the files I have that is HTML, JS, and Ruby

Comment: @user74542 Hmm.. I don't know about Atom but be sure to check the brackets plugin registry..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like Adobe Brackets has an extension called Beautify which can be found at https://brackets-registry.aboutweb.com/ and their GitHub location is https://github.com/drewhamlett/brackets-beautify